# Find value of complex function at a point

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be analytic in $ D = \{z \in \Bbb C : |z| < 1\}$, and $f(z) = 1$ when $Im(z) = 0$ and $-\frac{1}{2} \leq Re(z) \leq \frac{1}{2}$. What is the value of $f(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{1}{2})$?

I'm not really looking for complete solutions, but something like a hint or a clever way to tackle the problem, or a theorem that might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $g(z)=f(z)-1$. Identity theorem is helpful.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have another look at the problem.